# how to pass ObservableCollection from one page1 to page2 without use MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to pass ObversableCollecion temp from page1 to page2 ,when I click the button in page1.But I don't wan't to use MVVM,just be simnple.My code are as follows:
page1:

```
     public ObservableCollection<Staff> Staff_Collection { get; set; }
    private void button_click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page1 page1= new Page1();
        page1.Staff_Show = Staff_Collection;
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(page1);}
```

page2:

```
public ObservableCollection<Staff> Staff_Show = new ObservableCollection<Staff>();
    public TaxBefore_Sum()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Staff_Show = new ObservableCollection<Staff>();
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: So the code for Page1 is navigation to `page1`? Do you have it mixed up and should be the other way around?

Comment: just be a wrong ,it's page2.make a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var whateverPage = new WhateverPage(whateverDataYouWantToPass);
this.NavigationService.Navigate(whateverPage);
```

Just make sure, the constructor for `WhateverPage` (the page you are navigating to) is overloaded to accept the item you are passing into it like this:

```
public WhateverPage(WhateverData data)
{
    // code here
}
```

So in your case, if you are navigating to a page called `Page2`, then you will create a constructor in that page like this:

```
public Page2(ObservableCollection<Staff> staff)
{
    // Now you have staff in Page2. You can assign it to a property or field
}
```

Comment: it's works ,I can get the data,but even I Binding data to DataGrid .Columns.it can't be show,thank you,very much